# Inequality involving logarithm

Tags: real-analysis, inequality, logarithms, radicals, substitution

I've seen the following inequality

$$
4(\sqrt{x}-\sqrt{y})^2\leq (x-y)(\log(x)-\log(y))
$$

How can I prove something like that? In general, I'm interested in any lower bound for

$$
(x-y)(\log(x)-\log(y)),
$$
so, any reference on that is appreciated!

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming $x>y>0$, the given inequality just follows from Cauchy-Schwarz:

$$ \int_{y}^{x}\frac{dt}{t}\int_{y}^{x}1\,dt \geq \left(\int_{y}^{x}\frac{dt}{\sqrt{t}}\right)^2.$$

Answer (score 5):

For $x=y>0$ it's obvious.

Since our inequality is symmetric, we can assume that $x=yt$, where $t>1$

and we need to prove that $f(t)\geq0$, where
$$f(t)=\ln{t}-\frac{4(\sqrt{t}-1)}{\sqrt{t}+1}=\ln{t}-\frac{4(\sqrt{t}+1-2)}{\sqrt{t}+1}.$$
But, $$f'(t)=\frac{1}{t}-\frac{4}{\sqrt{t}(\sqrt{t}+1)^2}=\frac{(\sqrt{t}-1)^2}{t(\sqrt{y}+1)^2}\geq0,$$
which says $f(t)\geq f(1)=0$